# Strange behavior using CSS border radius

Tags: cross-browser, css

Can someone explain me why the top-left and bottom-left corners are displayed in this way:

[image]

using the following CSS:

```
form .form-field
 {
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
 }
```

both input field and the textarea have "form-field" class. (same behavior in Safari, Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: Just to make sure, is there a red background-color specified in another element behind the form inputs?

Comment: That CSS alone will not produce any red background at all. You need to show more code.

Comment: maybe your code sample not complete? when i try your css, its work fine...

Comment: OMG... I'm an idiot... it was a "debug" style I did put before (yes red background)... I'm sorry for the stupid question :P

Comment: Also, the prefixes for moz and webkit border radius are not necessary

Comment: right (I just took a look here: http://caniuse.com/border-radius)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like T.J. noted, something has a red background on it that's higher up in your DOM tree. Adding the border radius to your corners is exposing that. Use your browser's inspector to find it. Should be a quick fix.